# Как обращаться к значениям в сводной таблице pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Добрый день,
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно обращаться к отдельным значениям в сводной таблице? Колонки от 1 до 12 это объекты даты преобразованные в индексы месяцов. Извиняюсь за скрин таблицы, но текст не получается корректно добавить. Мне нужно выбрать значение 04 South Region в колонке 8, например.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Или хотя бы подскажите где в документации посмотреть?)

Answer (score 1):

Перевести сводную таблицу во фрейм, с помощью to_frame().